# Include header file in different directory in c++

Tags: c++, makefile

I've been learning c++ and encountered the following question:
I have a directory structure like:

```
 - current directory

  - Makefile

  - include

     - header.h

  - src

      - main.cpp
```

**my header.h :**

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;

void print_hello();
```

**my main.cpp:**

```
#include "header.h"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    print_hello();
    return 0;
}

void print_hello()
{
    cout<<"hello world"<<endl;
}
```

**my Makefile:**

```
CC = g++
OBJ = main.o
HEADER = include/header.h 
CFLAGS = -c -Wall 

hello: $(OBJ) 
    $(CC) $(OBJ) -o $@

main.o: src/main.cpp $(HEADER)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean: 
    rm -rf *o hello
```

And the output of make is:

> g++ -c -Wall  src/main.cpp -o main.o
>   src/main.cpp:1:20: fatal error: header.h: No such file or directory
>   compilation terminated.
>   Makefile:10: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
>   make: *** [main.o] Error 1

What mistakes I have made in here. It's frustrating. Really appreciate any advice!

Comment: Add `-Iinclude/` to the compiler flags.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Answers go in the answer section.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You told the Makefile that `include/header.h` must be present, and you told the C++ source file that it needs `header.h` … but you did not tell the compiler where such headers live (i.e. in the "include" directory).

Do this:

```
CFLAGS = -c -Wall -Iinclude
```

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Where does it search for the include folder? Where it is getting executed?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sorry for the less info. I was asking about the relevance of -Iinclude flag. I didn't actually understand why it was used.

Answer (score 5):

You can either add a `-I` option to the command line to tell the compiler to look there for header files. If you have header files in `include/` directory, then this command should work for you.

```
gcc -Iinclude/
```

Since, you are using `makefile`, you can include this option in `CFLAGS` macro in your makefile.

```
CFLAGS = -Iinclude/ -c -Wall
```

OR

You can include header files using `#include "../include/header.h"`.

Comment: It's not `gcc` and it's hidden behind a Make variable anyway, but this is right in principle. Suggest putting `-Iinclude` in `CFLAGS`, for an upvote.

Comment: i have extended my answer @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps change your include line:

```
#include "include/header.h"
```

Assuming that's where your header exists - I'm making that assumption from your makefile

Comment: That should be `#include "../include/header.h"`.

Comment: @dxiv thx it works! But do u know any elegant way to include a header file in different directory? Just like I only need "#include "header.h"" in my main.cpp?

Comment: @J.Lin Like @πάνταῥεῖ said, add `-Iinclude/` to the compiler flags (and maybe change `"header.h"` to `<header.h>` on the `#include` line).