# How to add a new header file location in the compiler

Tags: c, linux, gcc, header-files

Various resources have mentioned about the `-I` option of gcc , but have not mentioned its syntax. I want to add a header file which is not present in the  default directory which are taken into consideration by the compiler for adding the header files at the compile time. How can I achieve it?

Comment: `man gcc`, search for `-I`

Answer (score 1):

Just as the man page says, follow the argument directly with the path.

```
gcc ... -I/path/to/headers ...
```

Comment: like this - gcc tst2.c -o tst2 -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-32/include/linux

Comment: Put the location arguments before the source to be compiled.

Comment: this - gcc -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-32/include/linux tst2.c -o tst2

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-I` option:

```
gcc -o foobar -I/path/to/headers -I/path/to/other foobar.c
```

You can also use the `C_INCLUDE_PATH` environment variable. You could set this up in your makefile:

```
C_INCLUDE_PATH = /path/to/headers:/path/to/other

foobar: foobar.c
    gcc -o foobar foobar.c
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either add a `-I` option to the command line to tell the compiler to look there for header files. If you have header files in include/ directory, then this command should work for you.

```
gcc -Iinclude/
```

There shouldn't be any space between `-I` compiler option and directory location.

If, you are using makefile, you can include this option in CFLAGS macro in your makefile.

```
CFLAGS = -Iinclude/ -c -Wall
```

OR

You can include header files using #include "../include/header.h".

Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38162070/include-header-file-in-different-directory-in-c/38162515#38162515).